# I can't figure out why HTML form not meeting requirements

Tags: html

I can't figure out whats wrong with my code- the sentences noted by asterisk are whats required, below that is my code.

- has exactly one input with a name of 'pet_name' and an associated label with the content 'Name'
- has exactly one 'select' element with a name of 'pet_type' and an associated label with the content 'Type'

```html
<div>
  <label for="Name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="pet_name">
</div>

<div>
  <label for="pet_type">Type</label>
  <select id="type" name="pet_type">
    <option value="Cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="Dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="Hamster">Hamster</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
    <option value="Zebra">Zebra</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: So what is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: Be more specific. What exactly is the problem with this code? You say `the sentences noted by asterisk are whats required`, but you don't have any asterisks. To use html validation then add `required` inside `<input >`. Could also add it to `<select >` but there's no point, since all your `<option>`s have a value so `pet_type` would always meet this kind of requirement. [Here's more help about client-side form validation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation)

Answer (score 4):

Labels and elements are matched by `id` attribute. Furthermore, they are case-sensitive, so they need to match in uppercase and lowercase letters.

You can find detailed information in [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label), for example.

```
<div>
  <label for="pet-name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="pet-name" name="pet_name">
</div>

<div>
  <label for="pet-type">Type</label>
  <select id="pet-type" name="pet_type">
    <option value="Cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="Dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="Hamster">Hamster</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
    <option value="Zebra">Zebra</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

`for` must be a case-sensitive match for the `id` (and not the `name`) of the element to which it refers.

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
  <div>
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="pet_name">
  </div>

  <div>
      <label for="type">Type</label>
      <select id="type" name="pet_type">
          <option value="Cat">Cat</option>
          <option value="Dog">Dog</option>
          <option value="Hamster">Hamster</option>
          <option value="Other">Other</option>
          <option value="Zebra">Zebra</option>
      </select>
  </div>
```

Using as for value the id it refers to